# Open Source Hardware software and patent license

Tags: multi-licensing, patents, hardware, firmware

I'm working on a hardware medical device which I'd like to open source without giving out my patent rights to potential competitors.

I'd like to open source the firmware/software part. What's patented is implemented in the combination of hardware and firmware.

What kind of license can I use for this? I'd like others to be able to build on top of the hardware, but not allow others to take the firmware/software and make a competitive product.

Comment: I have made a small but crucial change in your last sentence, which pretty much reverses the sense, but changes it to what I think you intended (and to something that parses somewhat better).  If that's not right, please change it back and accept my apologies.

Comment: @MadHatter The thing with open source licenses is that all i've seen grant patents  rights automatically. I'm fine with others using the software for whatever reason, just not the patented part.

Comment: [This answer](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/7049/9558) would be of interest.